# git error: unable to index file FacebookSDK.framework/Headers

Tags: xcode, git

I use git through Xcode. It used to be fine, but since I reinstalled to new OSX (I keep my code in a Dropbox folder, so after re-install I just re-opened the project from there), I cannot commit anymore.

Here's the error I get:

```
error: unable to index file FacebookSDK.framework/Headers
fatal: updating files failed
```

Any ideas how to resolve this? My experience with git is very basic.

Comment: I am also having this problem! Ever find a solution?

Comment: Not yet - no one suggests a solution, and I'm too 'green' with git to try and brew one up myself

Comment: Check the permissions on that folder

Answer (score 2):

Try do the following:

open terminal,

`cd` to the project folder

`cd` to FacebookSDK.framework/Headers

```
git add .
```

and then go back to XCode and commit again.

Edit: If you still can't commit from Xcode:

```
git commit -m "Trying to commit from command line"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac/) - Version control with Git - made easy.
In a beautiful, efficient, and powerful app.